# jNIce - stop executing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jNice to enhance some forms on my site.
jNice is called by adding class to the form ().

My question is - **how can I stop jNice from convering the form only in some parts of the form**??
I cannot see this option on the spec.

Any help much appreciated.

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way of changing calling of the jNice script:

In one before last line of the script we have:

```
$(function(){$('form.jNice').jNice();   });
```

if we change that to (form - > div(or whatever we want))

```
$(function(){$('div.jNice').jNice();    });
```

That way we can call jNice on whatever we want(element wrapper or element it self).

Reg